# how to create Asp.net + Next.js 13.4 + Nginx + docker-compose

Tags: asp.net-web-api, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy, next.js13

I need to create a docker-compose so that next.js acts as a client and sends all requests to asp.net which will act as a backend, and I also need to use Nginx to redirect to the frontend and backend api.
The problem is that no matter how hard I try, I can't get any data on the frontend through the next.js server components.

## Here are my docker-compose settings:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webshopproject
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebShopProject/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - "postgres_db"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=User ID=postgres;Password=123;Server=postgres_db;Port=5432;Database=postgres-db; IntegratedSecurity=true; Pooling=true;
    ports:
      - "5000:80"

  client:
    image: client
    container_name: client
    build:
      context: ./web-client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - "backend"
    volumes:
      - ./web-client/src:/app/src
      - ./web-client/public:/app/public
      - ./web-client/styles:/app/styles
      - ./web-client/tailwind.config.ts:/app/tailwind.config.ts
    restart: always
    command: npm run dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
 
  proxy:
    image: nginx:mainline
    container_name: proxy
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"

  postgres_db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:15.3-alpine3.18
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always

    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres-db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
 
volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

## Backend Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebShopProject/WebShopProject.csproj", "WebShopProject/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebShopProject/WebShopProject.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebShopProject"
RUN dotnet build "WebShopProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebShopProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebShopProject.dll"]
```

## Nginx nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes auto;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    sendfile on;

    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://client:3000;
        }
        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://backend:80/api/;
        }
    }
}
```

## Next.js Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:20-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

COPY tsconfig.json ./tsconfig.json
COPY postcss.config.js ./postcss.config.js
COPY next.config.js ./next.config.js
COPY components.json ./components.json
COPY next-env.d.ts ./next-env.d.ts

RUN npm ci

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

It looks like the containers don't communicate with each other, but if you use client components, everything works fine

This code works:

```
"use client";
import { User } from "@/types/user";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function ClientTestComponent() {
  const [data, setData] = useState<User>();
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:80/api/auth/user")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (!data) return <p>No user data</p>;

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {data?.login}/{data?.password}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

But this one is not:

```
import { User } from "@/types/user";
import { Suspense } from "react";

async function getData(): Promise<User> {
  const data: User = await fetch("http://localhost:80/api/auth/user")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });

  return data;
}

export default async function TestComponent() {
  const data = await getData();

  return (
    <>
      <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
        <div className=" bg-blue-300">
          {data ? <>{data?.login}</> : <>No user data</>}
        </div>
      </Suspense>
    </>
  );
}
```

How to fix it?